# Signal conversion in Image Processing

Tags: matlab

How can I solve this question in matlab and how do we find the answer?

[image: Graph of question]

I tried this code:

```
r1= input('enter r1: ');
r2= input('enter r2:');
s1= input('enter s1:');
s2= input('enter s2:');
r=[0 r1 r2 255], [0 s1 s2 255];
if r &lt; r1
s=r*(r1/s1);
elseif r1&lt;r &amp; r&lt;r2
x=tan((r2-r1)/(s2-s1))
s(r-r1)*x
else
s=r*(r2/s2)
end
plot(s);
```

I would be glad if you help.

Comment: It's essentially a thresholding function. A first step that I'd do is to create a vector `r = (0:256);` then logically index it using parameters `A` and `B`. Case a) would look something like `r(r < A | r > B) = 0;`.

Comment: I think you mean "code block" rather than "code blog".

Comment: @MichaelTr7 thank you for your concern.

Comment: Why is this a MATLAB question? The answer is `d)`, since the condition shown is `r[i] > A && r[i] < B`, but that isn't even valid MATLAB syntax. Please read [how do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), this post currently doesn't contain a specific issue related to your code, and is off topic

Comment: @Wolfie Sir, thank you for answer. I agree with you but this sketch made using matlab. This sketch might have something to do with it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're required to use MATLAB to prove your selected answer. Is that right?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Exactly so.

Comment: @Wolfie Sir, I couldn't solve 2 more questions like this and I posted it here but nobody could. You are knowledgeable about the subject. If you have a chance to take a look, i will be very happy. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Matrix Indexing/Indexing by Conditions to Evaluate Cases:

A method of doing this is by plotting the 3 effective transfer functions given by the options in the multiple-choice question. In this example, the transfer function without any condition is `s = r` where the input intensity, `r` is equal to the output intensity, `s = T(r)`. Here logical indexing is applied to the ramp/line `r`. By applying the condition/cases `a)`, `b)` and `c)` as follows:

**Case a):**

```
r(r < A | r > B) = 0;
```

**Case b):**

```
r(r > A | r < B) = 0;
```

**Case c):**

```
r(r < A & r > B) = 0;
```

Where in the brackets is the condition used to index the vector `r`. Wherever this condition is true the value of `r` being matrix indexed is set to `0`. Since none of the cases below match the transfer function depicted in the question the final answer should be option `d)`.

[image: Plotting Option a), b) and c)]

```
clc;
clear;

A = 60;
B = 160;

%Setting up the figure%
X_Position = 100;
Y_Position = 100;
Width = 1200;
Height = 300;
figure('Position', [X_Position Y_Position Width Height])

%Case a)%
r = (0:255);
r(r < A | r > B) = 0;
s = r;
subplot(1,3,1); plot(s,'LineWidth',2);
title("Option a)")
xlabel("r"); ylabel("T(r)");

%Case b)%
r = (0:255);
r(r > A | r < B) = 0;
s = r;
subplot(1,3,2); plot(s,'LineWidth',2);
title("Option b)")
xlabel("r"); ylabel("T(r)");

%Case c)%
r = (0:255);
r(r < A & r > B) = 0;
s = r;
subplot(1,3,3); plot(s,'LineWidth',2);
title("Option c)")
xlabel("r"); ylabel("T(r)");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: I accepted this answer. By the way, I couldn't solve 2 more questions like this and I posted it here but nobody could. If you have a chance to take a look, i will be very happy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813186/contrast-stretching-transformation-in-image-processing

Comment: Sir, I drew the graph below, but I could not do the above. I'll be glad if you take a look. https://i.ibb.co/d08pyR3/ss.jpg

Comment: Below graph:

A = 60;
B = 160;

%Setting up the figure%
X_Position = 100;
Y_Position = 100;
Width = 1200;
Height = 300;
figure('Position', [X_Position Y_Position Width Height])

%Case a)%
r = (0:256);
r(r > A & r < B) = 0;
s = r;
subplot(1,3,1); plot(s,'LineWidth',2);
title("Option a)")
xlabel("r"); ylabel("T(r)");

Comment: You have the code in C you can simply convert it to MATLAB.

Comment: Or use a similar indexing methods like the previous graphs in the last question.

Comment: I tried but couldn't draw it exactly like the below graph.

Comment: The below graph is look good, i can't do other above graph.

Comment: What part of your code isn’t working when trying to generate the rectangular graph?

Comment: r = (0:256 );
s = zeros(size(r ));
s(r > A & r < B) = 250 ;
subplot(1,3,2); plot(s,'LineWidth',2 );
title("Option b )")
xlabel("r"); ylabel("T(r )");

Comment: i can't start y[i]=25 & 255

Comment: Take a look at the workspace variables and plot each line of code it might help guide you to the solution.

Comment: If not a for-loop could be an alternative solution.

Comment: r = (0:256);
s = 25*ones(size(r));
s(r > A & r < B) = 255;
subplot(1,3,2); plot(s,'LineWidth',2);
title("Option b)")
xlabel("r"); ylabel("T(r)");

Comment: I think from a technical standpoint though the questions want you to use two variables and plot against one another.

Comment: If you know full answer say me :) I don't know much more  about transfer function.