# Contrast stretching transformation in Image Processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

[Graph and Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImGLF.jpg)

I tried to find answer of question with using matlab but i couldn't find it.

I tried this code for solving of the question.

My code block:

```
p1=[0,0];
p2=[75,5];
p3=[140,250];
p4=[255,255];
m1=(p1(1,2)-p2(1,2))/(p1(1,1)-p2(1,1));
m2=(p2(1,2)-p3(1,2))/(p2(1,1)-p3(1,1));
m3=(p3(1,2)-p4(1,2))/(p3(1,1)-p4(1,1));
c1=p1(1,2)-m1*p1(1,1);
c2=p2(1,2)-m2*p2(1,1);
c3=p3(1,2)-m3*p3(1,1);
% Transformation function
t=[];
for x=0:255
if(x<=p2(1,1))
t=[t (m1*x+c1)];
end
if(x>p2(1,1) && x<=p3(1,1))
t=[t (m2*x+c2)];
end
if(x>p3(1,1) && x<=p4(1,1))
t=[t (m3*x+c3)];
end
end
for n=1:s(1,1)
for m=1:s(1,2)
ot(n,m)=t(a(n,m)+1);
end
end
```

I don't know how to find answer of this question. I will be glad if you help.

Comment: A little tip to get more answers to questions is to explain your approach/attempt that you took in your block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I split the transform function into three distinct regions each with a unique slope. The slopes were evaluated by taking the difference in neighbouring `x` values the `Run` and the difference in neighbouring `y` values the `Rise`. The process of taking if statements depending on where the input intensity `r` falls will dictate which effective slope to use. The last step is to add the offset of each linear line. Finding the `Effective_Run` is a process of evaluating how far into the region the intensity value has fallen. This can be done by subtracting the `x` lower bound of the region by the intensity value. This will be dependent on the points. For region 2 the offset is `s1 = 30` and for region 3 the offset is `s2 = 230`.

In bracket notation the bounds of each region can described as:

Region 1: Range `[0, r1]`

Region 2: Range `(r1, r2)`

Region 3: Range `[r2, 255]`

[image: Contrast Stretching Transformation Results]

Please take the time to look over the logic and mathematics to ensure no mistakes in the following code:

---

```
r = input("Please input the intensity value, r: "); 
fprintf("\n");

r1 = 70;
r2 = 150;
s1 = 30;
s2 = 230;

Point_1 = [0 0];
Point_2 = [r1 s1];
Point_3 = [r2 s2];
Point_4 = [255 255];

x = 1;
y = 2;

%Slope of region 1%
Rise = Point_2(y) - Point_1(y);
Run = Point_2(x) - Point_1(x);
Slope_1 = Rise/Run;

%Slope of region 2%
Rise = Point_3(y) - Point_2(y);
Run = Point_3(x) - Point_2(x);
Slope_2 = Rise/Run;

%Slope of region 3%
Rise = Point_4(y) - Point_3(y);
Run  = Point_4(x) - Point_3(x);
Slope_3 = Rise/Run;

if r <= r1
fprintf("Region 1\n"); 
s = Slope_1*r;
fprintf("The output intensity, s = T(r) is: %.2f\n",s); 

elseif (r1 < r) && (r < r2)
fprintf("Region 2\n"); 
Constant_Offset = s1;
Relative_Run = (r - r1);
s = Slope_2*Relative_Run + Constant_Offset;
fprintf("The output intensity, s = T(r) is: %.2f\n",s); 

elseif r >= r2
fprintf("Region 3\n"); 
Constant_Offset = s2;
Relative_Run = (r - r2);
s = Slope_3*Relative_Run + Constant_Offset;
fprintf("The output intensity, s = T(r) is: %.2f\n",s); 
   
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Sir, thank you very much. I have last one more question, I would be glad if you look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805439/question-about-filters-in-image-processing

Comment: @Deeper Blue Sure, I’ll take a look.

Comment: Last question is very different. I found some answers but maybe all of them is wrong.